# Gibt es ein Wort analog zu Klassenkamerad aber bezüglich der Stufe?

Tags: single-word-request

Ich will einen Mitschüler beschreiben, der mit mir gemeinsam in der Stufe, aber nicht in der gleichen Klasse ist.

Gibt es ein analoges Wort zu Klassenkamerad, das sich auf die Stufe bezieht? Insbesondere sollte es auch auf Mitschüler in der Oberstufe passen. Ich dachte an Stufenkamerad, aber das scheint nicht zu existieren bzw. geläufig zu sein.

Comment: Meinst du *Stufe* wie *Oberstufe* oder wie in *Klassenstufe*? *Stufenkamerade* würde ich intuitiv mit letzterer Bedeutung verstehen.

Comment: Klassenstufe. Ich erwähnte Oberstufe nur, weil es in der Oberstufe den normalen Klassenverband nicht mehr gibt, weil jeder Schüler andere Kurse belegt.

Comment: Wieso hast du denn dann [user unknowns Antwort](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/38414/5999) akzeptiert, wenn sie überhaupt nicht das ausdrückt, was du suchst (sondern einen "Mitschüler [einer beliebigen Klassenstufe] der Oberstufe")?

Comment: Weil das Prinzip trotzdem anwendbar ist. Wenn es eine bessere Antwort gibt, akzeptiere ich die aber gerne.

Comment: Gut zu wissen. Viele andere Benutzer tun dies nämlich leider nicht, was dazu führt, dass Antwortende zum Teil eine geringere Motivation haben, auf Fragen mit einer bereits akzeptierten Antwort überhaupt noch eine Antwort zu verfassen.

Comment: Prinzipiell sollte man mit den Akzeptieren von Antworten ein paar Tage warten. Erst wenn genügend viele Antworten eingegangen sind, sollte man sie vergleichen und sich dann für die beste entscheiden.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: Prinzipiell muss ich widersprechen. Ein Akzeptieren bei der ersten akzeptablen Antwort ist vollkommen in Ordnung. Man wird dennoch über jede neue Antwort informiert und kann die Entscheidung m.W. immer revidieren, so lange mehr als eine Antwort vorhanden ist. Vielleicht auch sonst. Da die beste Antwort auch noch nach Jahren kommen kann müsste man sonst ewig warten. Die Wahrheit ist im Programm. Es wäre ein leichtes eine Mindestwartezeit zu programmieren, wenn man gewollt hätte.

Comment: Eine Schwierigkeit mit Mitschülern der Stufe ist, dass, wenn sie nicht im gleichen Jahrgang sind, mal in der gleichen Stufen sind, mal nicht. Sie können schon eine Stufe weiter oder noch eine zurück sein.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Stufenkamerad* ist vollkommen in Ordnung.

Es kommt natürlich ein bisschen darauf an, was für Anforderungen du an die "Existenz" bzw. "Geläufigkeit" des Wortes stellst. *Stufenkamerad* mag nicht im Duden stehen, aber eine Internetsuche bringt einen schnell zu diversen Belege für die Verwendung selbst in formellem Kontext (Zeitungen, s. https://www.taz.de/!326026/ oder https://www.derwesten.de/staedte/witten/ein-festival-des-freibiers-id8110415.html).

Ich habe *Stufenkamerad* in der Vergangenheit selber schon mehrfach verwendet und bin dabei noch nie auf Verständnisprobleme gestoßen. Zumindest für den mitteldeutschen und norddeutschen Sprachraum bin ich mir daher recht sicher, dass die Bedeutung auch für Leute, die das Wort noch nie gehört haben, transparent ist.

Quelle: Deutscher Muttersprachler

Comment: Unter einem *»Stufenkameraden«* würde ich ad hoc jemanden verstehen, der neben mir auf derselben Stufe einer längeren Treppe sitzt. Zumindest in Österreich kann ich mir nicht vorstellen, dass jemand dieses Wort freiwillig verwendet. Da mag auch daran liegen, dass man seine Mitschüler hier eher selten als *Kameraden* bezeichnet.

Comment: Über die Verwendung in Österreich kann ich tatsächlich nichts sagen, habe meine Antwort entsprechend eingeschränkt.

Answer (score 5):

Ja.

Im Deutschen darf man Wörter miteinander verketten. Also schreibt man, wie Du, was man sagen will auf:

> Es sollte auf Mitschüler in der Oberstufe passen.

Isoliert die Substantive:

> Mitschüler, Oberstufe

Sortiert sie um, so dass die Eingrenzung der Kategorie vorne steht

> Oberstufe, Mitschüler

Und verbindet das Ergebnis zu einem einzelnen Hauptwort:

> **Oberstufenmitschüler**

Ob das Wort vor Dir ein Literaturpreisgewinner oder Oberstudienrat schon mal benutzt hat oder nicht spielt keine Rolle, man darf auch jungfräuliche Begriffe die wohlgebildet sind ohne Zertifikat benutzen.

Ob sie einem gefallen ist eine andere Frage. *Mitschüler der Oberstufe* ist eine Spur länger und es gibt selten eine Belohnung dafür, nur ein Wort zu benutzen, wo man auch dreie benutzen kann.

Comment: »Oberstufenmitschüler« hat für mich einen sehr militärischen oder bürokratischen Beigeschmack, vergleichbar mit *Oberstabswachtmeister* oder *Baufachoberinspektor*. Damit würde ich keinen (ehemaligen) Schulkollegen bezeichnen wollen.

Comment: Jahrgangsstufengleicher Schulkollege wird Dir dann wohl auch nicht gefallen. Woher Du militärische Beiklänge nimmst ist mir rätselhaft; das "Kamerad" in Klassenkamerad finde ich deutlich militärischer. Das bürokratieaffine kann ich nachvollziehen. Da Schulen und deren Struktur eine öffentliche Aufgabe sind ist es wohl kaum vermeidlich, will man die Präzision von "Jahrgangsstufe" erhalten.

Answer (score 4):

Ich halte das vom OP vorgeschlagene *Stufenkamerad* durchaus für angemessen, auch wenn er nicht unbedingt verbreitet zu sein scheint. Wenn klar ist, dass der Kontext die Schulzeit ist, leuchtet die Bedeutung zumindest in Südwestdeutschland ein. Dabei ist allerdings zu beachten, dass *Stufe* zwei Bedeutungen haben kann:

- die Klassenstufe (1./2./3./...)
- die generelle Stufe in der Schullaufbahn, die jeweils mehrere Klassenstufen umfasst (z.B. im Gymnasium Unter-, Mittel- und Oberstufe)

Während ich persönlich *Stufenkamerad* intuitiv mit der ersten Bedeutung assoziieren würde (nicht zuletzt, weil die Unterteilung in Unter-, Mittel- und Oberstufe für die Schüler weitgehend willkürlich und bedeutungslos ist), besteht natürlich die Gefahr, dass andere dies anders sehen.

Statt dessen halte ich daher den Begriff **Jahrgangskamerad** (gegebenenfalls mit angehängtem "in/aus der Schule", falls der Kontext nicht klar ist) für geeigneter. Der *Jahrgang* bezieht sich im Schulkontext im Allgemeinen auf Geburts-, Einschulungs- oder Abschlussjahr der Schüler. Abgesehen von Ausnahmen (wiederholte Klassen etc.) sind all diese Jahrgänge aber einigermaßen synchron, sodass eine Gruppe von Schülern in derselben Klassenstufe typischerweise als "ein Jahrgang" bezeichnet wird.

Answer (score 3):

Eine Antwort aus österreichsicher Sicht. (Ich vermute, dass *»Kamerad«* und *»Kollege«* in D und Ö mit voneinander abweichender Häufigkeit verwendet werden.)

Das Wort *Klassenkamerad* als Bezeichnung für einen Mitschüler wird in Österreich zwar nicht als falsch, aber als »eher deutsch« (im Sinn von: *eher nicht österreichisch*) empfunden.

*Kameraden* sind in Österreich eher Soldaten, mit denen man gemeinsam beim Bundesheer war, oder Mitglieder derselben Feuerwehr, Rettungsmannschaft oder ähnlicher Zusammenschlüsse, bei denen eine hierarchische Organisation und Pflichterfüllung im Vordergrund stehen.

Eine Person, die mit einem in dieselbe Klasse geht, nennt man in Österreich eher

> Klassenkollege

Ein Schüler desselben Jahrgangs ist ein

> **Jahrgangskollege,**

was auch die Antwort auf die gestellte Frage sein dürfte.

Ein Schüler, der zur selben Zeit dieselbe Schule besucht, ist ein

> Schulkollege

Diese Begriffe schließen einander nicht aus. Jeder Klassenkollege ist auch ein Jahrgangskollege, und alle Jahrgangskollegen sind Schulkollegen.

Daneben gibt es den *»Mitschüler«*, bei dem aber nicht klar definiert ist, ob das jemand ist, der nur in derselben Schule war, oder ob er auch in derselben Klasse war. Dieselbe Unschärfe existiert beim *»Schulfreund«*, wobei hier auch noch eine freundschaftliche Beziehung hervorgehoben wird, die beim bloßen Mitschüler oder Schulkollegen kein definierender Bestandteil ist.

Comment: Ich kann bestätigen, dass der österreichische Gebrauch von *Kollege* damit offenbar von dem in Deutschland abweicht. In DE sind *Kollegen* ausschließlich Personen, mit denen man sich einen Arbeitgeber geteilt hat. Nur in Jugendsprache werden Kommilitonen, Freunde, Mitschüler oder Ähnliches als *Kollegen* bezeichnet (in Sätzen, die typischerweise mit "ey alder" oder so was beginnen ;) ).

Comment: Und wenn ich ein zweites Mal +1 machen könnte, würde ich das für den letzten Absatz über die Mehrdeutigkeit von *Mitschüler* und *Schulfreund* tun.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: Ich habe schon oft gehört, dass sich Leute betriebsübergreifend Kollege genannt haben. Das könnte branchenabhängig sein - eher auf dem Bau, als bei Bankern. Die erste Vermutung wäre aber gleicher Betrieb. Informell habe ich auch schon "pack mal mit an, Kollege" für Wildfremde gehört, "Kollege, hier ist Halteverbot!"

Comment: "betriebsübergreifend Kollege genannt" - na ja, aber dennoch besteht da ein Arbeitskontext. Den Umstand, dass man vielleicht nicht denselben Arbeitgeber, aber (dank desselben Projekts) zum Beispiel denselben Auftraggeber oder zumindest sozusagen dasselbe Arbeitsfeld (wenn man auf einer Messe einen Mitarbeiter eines anderen Unternehmens trifft) hat, hatte ich nicht bedacht, er zählt aber in der Tat ebenso. Die Beispiele mit den Wildfremden zähle ich eher zur genannten Jugend- oder vielleicht insgesamt informellen Umgangssprache.

Answer (score 2):

Ja, allerdings nicht klassenstufenunabhängig. So gibt es

> Mitzwölftklässler
>   Mitelftklässler
>   …
>   Miterstklässler

Des Weiteren ist es aus meiner Erfahrung eher unüblich, dass Schüler zwischen Mittelstufenschülern und Oberstufenschülern unterscheiden. Meistens sind sich die Zehntklässler (im achtjährigen Gymnasium) nicht einmal bewusst, dass sie schon Oberstufenschüler sind. Stattdessen wird zwischen den konkreten Klassenstufen unterschieden (siehe oben) oder zwischen den Schularten.

Ein

> Mitoberstufenschüler

ist also möglich, aber ungewöhnlich.

Comment: Impliziert (o.B.d.A.) *Mitelftklässler*, dass die Person nur während der 11. Klasse den entsprechenden Status hatte (und beispielsweise vorher und nachher auf eine andere Schule ging)? Ich bin mir da nicht sicher.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Es sagt lediglich über die 11. Klasse etwas aus.

Answer (score 2):

Man sagt gewöhnlich *Mitschüler aus der Parallelklasse* oder *Mitschüler aus der selben Stufe*, weil es kein spezielles Wort dafür gibt. Konstruiert man eins, wird man Akzeptanzprobleme für dieses neue Wort haben.